How to limit max current in a constant voltage SMPS?
I have 5 V 10 A SMPS. Using this, I tried to charge a 3.2 V 10 Ah lithium cell.
But the current shot up to 16 A and got stuck there. The cell got very hot.
Is there any easy way to limit the current to the 10 A?
Efficiency is not an issue here.. I just want constant 10 A out of my 5 V SMPS.
I tried to put a 0.1 Ω 10 W resistor which drops 1 V and limits the current. But the resistor also getting very hot. Any other clever ways?

Do not do that. Not only are you overstressing your power supply, it would also try to float the battery to 5 V, which would cause it to fail.

you could inline a PNP transistor and tie it to ground with a resistor, or better, a small constant current source like from a tl431. This acts as a constant current source to limit the current and voltage to the cell. You still need to manually disconnect when full, (or use a window comparator) and the precise current delivered varies with the PNP's temp/Hfe, but it can be effective enough for charging to be safe, and is certainly better than the setup described. Better would be to use an SMPS with CV and CC built in, rather than a fixed voltage no current limit supply.

You can use a dedicated IC that has all the features for charging the battery implemented. Something like this:
https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm8061.html
There are other brands and more or less integrated solutions available.
At any rate, do not charge the lithium cell with currents that are too high, because it can be dangerous.
Regarding the resistor: well, that's kinda a primitive solution, and if you don't want it to get hot, use bigger resistor (bigger in size, rated for higher power).
If you really insist on simple solution you can use laboratory power supply and limit the current (also not recommended) or implement a simple current limit, see here: Help dimensioning resistors in a two NPN transistor current limiter circuit

That IC max current is 2A but I need 10A. Also it seems the two NPN transistor current limiter works in mA range only. In my use, I'm stopping the charging once the cell completes CC phase, that is im allowing it go only up to 4.10V..

"that IC" was just an example. there are many like it.
NPN tranisistor circuit would also work at higher currents, you just need to re-calculate the parts according to your desires. There are plenty NPN transistors out there that are capable of 10A.

Would this one be suitable replacement for "that IC": https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24610.pdf

Ohkay I'll study the two NPN transistor circuit and try to replace transistors with more power ones and see...

Thanks I have a look at the pdf.. it seems above my comprehension level. But the two transistor ckt looks cool I'm going to try it

IT will be very hard to complete this task with very basic knowledge. It's quite complex plus high current. i highly recommend getting an off-the shelf charger.

Maybe try adding two silicon diodes in series with the cell and power supply. The voltage drop across them might be enough to lower the voltage and thus current to a more reasonably safe limit. 2x diodes might get close to a 1.7 V drop. 5 V - 1.4 V = 3.6 V which is closer to the maximum a 3.2 V lithium cell should charge too. Plus when the current is higher the voltage drop on the diodes will be higher, maybe as much as 1 V so you'll get 2 V drop and limit current even more. Slightly self limiting. It's crude but simple. Would definitely need to keep an eye on it and make sure the cell is always in safe charging conditions. But as other have stated, a proper charger designed to limit current and voltage would be much more advisable.

While this would theoretically/approximately work for the bulk phase, this is a bad idea as it still presents 5v to the cell once the current drops off as the cell charges. Once the cell is full, the diodes no longer drop 1.7v, or anything close, they might only drop a few mv, and that can fry the cell.

Agreed. It wasn't meant to be a final solution to charging the cells. Just an idea to lower the current without using resistors
